# Lua - match only words outside {} braces in string and replace or append the words with substring

Tags: string, lua

I have various strings with forms similar to:

> This is a **sentence** outside braces{*sentence*{} with some words. {This is a
>   *sentence* inside braces with some words.}{This is a second *sentence*
>   inside braces.} Maybe some more words here for another **sentence**.

With Lua, I want to only match specific words in the string which are outside the "{}" braces. For example, I might want to match the word "**sentence**" outside the braces but not the occurrences of "*sentence*" inside the braces. I want to only match the bolded occurrences of the word not the italicized ones.

How to do it?

---

EDIT: What if I want append or replace the matched words while keeping the substrings inside the braces intact?

Example: append "word" to sentence:

> This is a **sentenceword** outside braces{sentence{} with some words. {This is a
>   sentence inside braces with some words.}{This is a second sentence
>   inside braces.} Maybe some more words here for another **sentenceword**.

Comment: any own ideas? attempts?

Comment: If your braces are balanced, then try `your_text = (your_text.."{}"):gsub("(.-)(%b{})", function(a, b) return a:gsub("sentence", "replacement")..b end):sub(1,-3)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Why do you always write your answers in the comments? ;)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - IMO, a concise answer is a good answer.  But SO encourages long answers.  So, I write comments :-)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this would be to replace all the brackets with a zero length strings in a temporary variable which you can then use to search for whatever you like.

You can easily do this using Lua's pattern matching and the following simple `gsub` code:

```
local tempStr = startStr:gsub("{.-}","")
```

The `.-` is the part that makes it grab everything between the `{` and `}` and `gsub` then replaces it all with a blank string.

---

**Edit:** The issue with the above method, as DarkWiiPlayer has pointed out is that the first open brace mathces with the first close brace which is incorrect.

The way around that is to use balanced braces (`%b`) as DarkWiiPlayer has recommended in his answer, like so:

```
local tempStr = startStr:gsub("%b{}","")
```

Comment: Would I be able to restore the original substrings inside the braces with this? I want to replace or append the words outside the braces which I have matched while keeping the substrings inside the braces intact.

Comment: You would have two variables, one with the braces (the original string) and the other without any braces (the new string). Can you tell me a bit more about what you would be appending or replacing along with an example or two please. The best way would probably be to edit your original question.

Comment: "consider{a string {like} this} one" matching "this" when it shouldn't

Comment: I originally had `.*` because it delt with this before I realised it would also ignore any legit words between two different braces. So I changed it to `-` forgetting that now the above would happen. Oops.

Answer (score 3):

```lua
local function weird_match(word, str)
   return str:gsub("%b{}", ''):match(word)
end
```

- Replace [balanced pairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) of `{` and `}` with the empty string
- Find the desired pattern (`word`) in the resulting string
- Return the matched word (or its captures, if it has any)